# Ошибка описания виртуальных функций

Tags: c++builder, virtual, c++

Пишу простенький код:

```
class LexicalAnalyzer {
public:
    LexicalAnalyzer();
    virtual String run();
    virtual String step();
};
```

но неожиданно на C++ Builder XE7 выдаёт ошибку:

> E2462 'virtual' can only be used with
> non-template member functions

Что тут не так? Вроде раньше такое прокатывало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заработало.

Билдер не знал про `String`, надо добавить `#include <vcl.h>`.